# Vertically align a div within a position:absolute parent

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the `.container` div is absolutely positioned as half of it's parent. Now, within this container, I want to vertically align the `.content` div. I am having trouble because of `.container` being positioned absolutely.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2La6vdrc/2/

I want the "Hello" content to be centered vertically

I'll need this for IE8+.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `position` of content and then combine `top` and transforms `translateY` to vertically centre it:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    background-color:white;

    /* Note browser prefixes */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);

    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/2La6vdrc/5/)

---

Since you need to support IE8, you can use an extra container as a cell and have your original container display as a table. You can then use `vertical-align`:

```css
.out {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="content">
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does translateY work on IE8? Updated question to include this necessity

Comment: @Harry No IE8 doesn't support transform. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow a pattern similar to this:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
}
.content {
  position: absolute or relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

heres your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2La6vdrc/6/

More reading on vertical centering at the CSS-Tricks blog:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: does translateY work on IE8? Updated question to include this necessity

Comment: shucks, no you can't.  You could use modernizr to use this as a solution then provide an alternate for IE8 though.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css calc to position it 50% of height and subtract the half of the divs heigth you want to center, see the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidbucka/oLaavyj1/

```
.content {
  background-color:white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px; /*height you want*/
  top: calc(50% - 20px); /* 50%-half of height l.21 */
}
```

there are different ways, let me know if you need another one.

P.S.: just read the change in the question for ie8 support - i guess thats not supported in that version

Answer (score 1):

with `display:table;` IE8+ --> http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20table

now depending on what you really need to achieve with `display:table;` as you can see the `background-color` doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/2La6vdrc/8/

```
<div class="out">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <p>hello</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.out {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table; /* check this line */
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: solid 5px red;
}

.content {
    background-color:white;
    display: table-cell; /* check this line */
    vertical-align: middle; /* check this line */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to use CSS FlexBox.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

FlexBox has become my preferred method for fluidly aligning elements in a way that feels semantically appropriate.